# Nuget pack ignoring my content and lib folder

Tags: nuget-package

I'm trying to create a nuget package by using the convention as described [here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#From_a_convention_based_working_directory)

I think my csproj's output folder looks correct:

```
[projectPath]/bin/Debug/  
  - myProject.dll  
  /build  
    - myProject.props  
  /content  
    - myRuleset.ruleset  
    - CustomDictionary.xml
```

The spec file is the default generated spec file with the redundant nodes removed (like update info etc)

I run `nuget pack -build`  after which the following content is packed in a nupkg file (left out _rels and package as they aren't relevant to the problem):

```
myProject.1.0.1.0.nupkg  
  /content  
    /build  
      - myProject.props  
  /lib  
    - myProject.dll
```

Why is my build folder inside my content folder?
Where have my content folder's files gone to?

Answer (score 4):

The default generated spec file just gives you a starting point. User need to modify the spec file for nuget pack to work correctly with your project structure.

Please refer to this link http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference, for how to include files to the package.

There is a section named "Specifying Files to Include in the Package" should give more insights.

Comment: That is indeed what I did now, but I thought that following the convention would render the same result. Guess I'm wrong then.

Comment: The lib/content/tools conventions don't work for me neither. Using NuGet.exe v2.8.60318.667. Explicity writing a <files> section in .nuspec does work, however, and also seems preferable in that you can pull in files form anywhere.

Comment: @MartinConnell same here, it seems like they removed the conventions? I've spent the past 2 days being very confused